# What do I need to do to extend the width of a doorway?

Tags: interior, door-frame

I want to make the doorway from my kitchen 39 inches longer opening the kitchen up to the living room. The door way that we have now is only 36 inches wide and I want to make it 75 inches wide.

What do I need to make the door open wider?  Do I need to add onto the existing header or add a whole new header and if so what size of header do I need to install where it is a interior wall in the center of the house and what do I do to get around the a/c vent over the existing door way between the kitchen and living room ?

Comment: Is the wall you're targeting a structural wall? That makes all the difference...

Comment: If you don't know whether this is a loadbearing wall, do *nothing* until you establish this. (If it's parallel to the floor joists it is *probably* not loadbearing... except in older houses which may have settled and not be distributing the load the way one would expect them to.)